# Generate csv from sh script by Pentaho in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sh, export-to-csv, pentaho-spoon

At first, I created a test.sh from Pentaho Spoon which included the query to create .csv in Ubuntu

In  test.sh file contains this query

```
psql -h 111.111.111.11 -p 5432 -U usr -d db_name --pset footer -A -F"|" -c "select * from customer"  > //home/cust.csv
```

Secondly, run this test.sh file by Pentaho Spoon (Using Execute a shell script) in Ubuntu

```
bash test.sh
```

After that I get this file "cust.csv?". However, I dont know why this "?" comes after .csv , I cannot use this file in next step due to "?"

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The issues probably comes from extra invisible characters in the test.sh file.

Also note that `test.sh` is enough in the `Script` box (no need for the `bash`), and there must be no extra invisible character, nor even a \n or \r.

I am taking from granted that in the Ubutu terminal `./test.sh` produce the correct file, and that you have some reason to use the `Insert script` mode rather than giving the `Script File Name` mode.